# How to test if a value of any type can represent an integer

Tags: python

> Write a function integer_type that consumes a value of any type and produces "Even integer" if it is an even integer, "Odd integer" if it is an odd integer, and "Not an integer" otherwise.

My code:

```
def integer_type(som):
    if type(som)==type(0):
        if som%2==0:
        return "Even integer"
        else:
        return "Odd integer"
    else:
        return "Not an integer"
x= input()
print(integer_type(x))
```

Everytime I run it, it prints "Not an integer" whatever the value I enter.

I tried a different problem with elifs instead and it made no difference. I still obtain the very last "else" return for my print.

> Write a function off_peak that consumes any type of data and determines if the time is eligible for off peak rates. Your function should produce one of the following outputs: "Off peak", "Peak", and "Not a time". Off-peak rates are based on 24-hour time, for values less than 9 or greater than 17.

```
def off_peak(any):
    if type(any)==type(0) and any<9 and any>17:
        return "Off peak"
    elif type(any)==type(0) and 9<any<17 and 0<any<23:
        return "Peak"
    else:
        return "Not a time"

x= input("Peak Dector:")
print(off_peak(x))
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

Comment: try printing the type after you take input, it should clear everything up.

Comment: And don't use type, use `isinstance` instead. Like in `isinstance(something, int)` or even better `isinstance(something, numbers.Integral)`

Comment: What makes you think x is an integer? Have you tried printing x or properties of x to see what you're working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is correct and does exactly what you want it to do, the problem here is that `input()` always returns a string, so when you pass its output to `integer_type()` it sees that it's a string and returns `Not an integer`.
To see this, try using this code:

```
def integer_type(som):
if type(som)==type(0):
    if som%2==0:
        return "Even integer"
    else:
        return "Odd integer"
else:
    return "Not an integer"
x= 'integer?'
y = 5
z = 4
print(integer_type(x))
print(integer_type(y))
print(integer_type(z))
```

It will print exactly what you want:

```
Not an integer
Odd integer
Even integer
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should convert the input to an int before comparing:

`print(integer_type(int(x)))`

Comment: if convert the input to an int. then there is not need to check if `type(any)==type(0)` in the function `integer_type`

Comment: This won't do what the OP wants: if you enter something else than an integer, it will raise an exception and the `integer_type` function will never be called.

Answer (score 1):

I'll suppose that you're using Python 3.

`input` always returns a string. What you first want to test is if this string can represent a valid integer.

You can simply try to convert it, and you will know that it is invalid if an errors occurs (a `ValueError`, in this case).

If we want the function to accept any type of input, including floats and strings like "3.00", or any object, things get a bit more complicated. You could rewrite your function like this:

```
def integer_type(value):
    # int("3.00") would raise a ValueError, though 3 is an odd integer.
    # We start by converting our input value to a float. 
    # float(value) will accept integers, floats or strings,
    # it will raise a TypeError for None or other invalid types.
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        # If it isn't a float, it's definitely not an integer
        return "Not an integer"

    # Now we check that our float is an integer:
    if not value.is_integer():
        return "Not an integer"

    if value % 2 == 0:
        return "Even integer"
    else:
        return "Odd integer"
```

The input of the function can be a string, an integer, a float, or whatever. Whether it can be converted to a valid integer or not, it will always give the expected result:

```
print(integer_type(3))
print(integer_type("3"))
# Odd integer
# Odd integer
print(integer_type(3.1))
print(integer_type("3.1"))
# Not an integer
# Not an integer
print(integer_type(3.00))
print(integer_type("3.00"))
# Odd integer
# Odd integer
print(integer_type(-4.00))
print(integer_type("-4.00"))
# Even integer
# Even integer
print(integer_type("abc"))
# Not an integer
print(integer_type(None))
# Not an integer
```

If you're using Python 2, replace `input` by `raw_input`.

Comment: Thank you I now grasp why these functions aren't working, your solution is a little bit beyond my understanding right now but i'll try to learn those skills. If floats accepts integers, floats and integers why does making the input a float, x=(float(input()) not work?

Comment: Well, sorry for the complication ;-) I started much more simple, added a few test cases and saw that they didn't pass, that's the simplest complete solution I could find... `x=(float(input())` will raise an error if you input a string like "abc", as it can't be a valid `float`, and your function wouldn't get called. We must try the conversion *in the function* to treat the error as we want.